# Is there a way to use raw html with the markdown used in odyssey.js?

Tags: carto, html, django, odyssey-js, markdown

I use odyssey.js in part of my Django site. The map part of it is all working fine but I need to add some `<i-frame>` elements. I'm not sure what flavour of markdown it is and can't figure out how to add any raw html. {% autoescape off %} stops the <> tags from being escaped but using |safe doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: You might have better luck on stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

The Tech Crunch article *[CartoDB’s Odyssey.js Is An Open-Source Tool For Telling Stories With Interactive Maps](https://techcrunch.com/2014/07/08/cartodbs-odyssey-js-is-an-open-source-tool-for-telling-stories-with-interactive-maps/)* points at [Daring Fireball](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) as the type of markdown.

There is an associated [discussion list](https://pairlist6.pair.net/mailman/listinfo/markdown-discuss) on the Daring Fireball site so perhaps it would be the resource from which to get a definitive answer.

Comment: I already use daring fireball for my regular blog posts but the same rules don't seem to apply when using odyssey. I've a feeling they've tweaked the settings.

Comment: Yes i agree Oliver. I have used many tests and Odyssey.js uses only some parts of Daring Fireball's markdown.